# Ember and custom endpoint

Tags: ember.js

I have a problem with ember in a custom endpoint and a component

I need to get data from the custom endpoint when using a simple findAll the component works perfect but the findAll not going to custom endpoint, When I use adapter ajax goes to the custom endpoint and then pushPayload the data to the store but the component does not work.

What is the best way to call to an custom endpoint from Ember?

Comment: This is too broad of a question with vague description.  `using a simple findAll the component works perfect but the findAll not going to custom endpoint` What does **not going** mean? Further, what does **but the component works perfect** entail? You might want to read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Might want to take a look @ ic.ajax for custom queries and then push-to-store to keep it emberish